# Add historic data to system versioned temporal table (SQL Server 2017)

Tags: sql-server, database, temporal-database

I have a system versioned temporal table in SQL Server 2017. I need to add data to it that has the same primary keys as data already in the table, but I don't want to send the current table data to history table. In essence, I want to add data directly to the history table, as I am trying to add historic data to my database. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What happens when you wrote the query and tried to insert into the history table?

Comment: When I try to insert values by query, I get this error: "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."

Comment: And when you add the valid from/to columns?

Comment: That's the thing: I am inserting the same way I would in the normal table and it's giving me this error, so perhaps there is something different that I have do, but I am not sure what it is.

Comment: Even if i right click on the history table in SMSS, I don't get an option to make an insert query. Only to select or create.